# Ability search from the child table with parameters in Prisma MySQL in one query

Tags: node.js, api, express, rest, prisma

I have two tables customers and business and I want to be able to fetch from two tables in one query.

**Customer Model (Parent table)**

```
model business {
  id                Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  customer_id       Int
  registered_no     String?
  business_name     String?   @unique
  subscription_name String?   @db.VarChar(100)
  name_of_plan      String?
  name_of_plaza     String?   @db.Text
  state             String?   @db.VarChar(35)
  city              String?
  street_name       String?
  street_no         String?
  lga               String?
  area              String?
  location          String?   @db.VarChar(55)
  is_coverage       Boolean   @default(false)
  created_at        DateTime  @default(now())
  updated_at        DateTime  @default(now())
  
  customer          customer @relation(fields: [customer_id], references: [id])

  @@index([customer_id, registered_no])
}
```

**Business Model (Child Table)**

```
model customer {
  id                Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
  unique_identifier String?     @unique @db.VarChar(155)
  od_id           String?     @db.VarChar(10)
  surname           String?     @db.VarChar(55)
  firstname         String?     @db.VarChar(55)
  middlename        String?     @db.VarChar(55)
  othernames        String?     @db.VarChar(55)
  phone             String      @db.VarChar(13)
  mobile            String?     @db.VarChar(13)
  email_address     String      @unique @db.VarChar(155)
  home_address      String      @db.Text
  state             String?     @db.VarChar(35)
  city              String?
  street_name       String?
  street_no         String?
  lga               String?
  area              String?
  location          String?     @db.VarChar(55)
  status            Int?
  customer_type     String?     @db.VarChar(9)
  country_code      String?     @db.MediumText
  date_of_birth     String?     @db.VarChar(15)
  how_did_you_hear  String?     @db.VarChar(55)
  created_at        DateTime    @default(now())
  updated_at        DateTime    @default(now())
  business          business[]

  @@index([unique_identifier, phone, mobile])
}
```

Basically whenever a user searches for a record in the business model and also joined the customer model based on the search parameters from the user's input, it should display the business records and include the customer records where the search parameters matches both the customer and business data.

Here is my current query:

```
async getAllCustomers (req, res) {

        const records_per_page = Number(req.query.records_per_page) || 20;
        const current_page = Math.max(Number(req.query.page_number || 1), 1)

        let recordCount

        const options = {
            take: records_per_page, //total number of items on a pge
            skip: (current_page - 1) * records_per_page,
            orderBy: { id: 'desc' },
        }

        options.select =  {
            subscription_name: true,
            business_name: true,
            name_of_plan: true,
            customer: {
              select: {
                id: true,
                unique_identifier: true,
                phone: true,
                mobile: true,
                email_address: true,
                home_address: true
              },
            },
        }

        const countOptions = {}

        if(req.query.filter){
            const filter = req.query.filter     

            if(filter === "business_internet"){
                options.where = { 
                    subscription_name: { in: [ BusinessCategories.DualPlay, BusinessCategories.TriplePlay, BusinessCategories.TriplePlayX ] } 
                }
                
            }else if(filter === "business_wifi"){
                options.where = {
                    subscription_name: { equals: BusinessCategories.BusinessWifi }
                }
            }

            countOptions.where = options.where

        }

        if(req.query.search){
**//I know there is something wrong here but I can't seems to find what exactly**
            options.select = {
                customer: {
                    where: {
                        email_address: { contains: req.query.search }
                      }
                }
            }
            // options.where = {
            //     OR: [
            //         { email_address: { contains: req.query.search }},
            //         { surname: { contains: req.query.search }},
            //         { firstname: { contains: req.query.search }},
            //         { state: { contains: req.query.search }},
            //     ],
            // }

            // countOptions.where = options.where

        }

        let customers = await prisma.business.findMany(options)
        recordCount = await prisma.business.count(countOptions)

        res.status(200).json({data: customers ,
            pagination: {
                current_page: current_page,
                totalCount: recordCount,
                pageCount: Math.ceil(recordCount / records_per_page)
            }
        })
    }
```

I know there is something wrong with the req.query.search code block but I can't seems to find out what is it. Please I need guide on what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able fix this after additional digging into the problem. Below is the snippet I added for the search params

```
if(req.query.search){
            options.where = {
                customer: {
                  OR: [
                    {phone: {contains: req.query.search }},
                    {surname: { contains: req.query.search }},
                    {email_address: { contains: req.query.search }},
                  ]
                },
              }

            countOptions.where = options.where

        }
```

See reference here: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#filter-on--to-many-relations